# Rotate Text Cairo, Transformation matrix

Tags: graphics, cairo

http://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html

I have been using Cairo Vector Graphics Library for some work, and I quite understand some parts :-

What is the default value of the transformation matrix ?

When do I need the transformation matrix anyway ?

Suppose I don't want to rotate text, will I still need to set it , will it still be set ?

I know it is very nooblike, & I must investigate it on my own, but I cant quite understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default transformation is the identity matrix. This matrix doesn't change values, so (x, y) stays the same when transformed by the identity matrix.

Rotating text is one reason that you might need this. If you don't rotate text, then you likely don't need the matrix. Most stuff shouldn't need a transformation.

If you need the matrix depends on which other stuff you do. For example, if you call other code and want to scale up the drawing by a factor of two, you could do this with a transformation matrix.

So the short version: If you don't know what to do with the transformation matrix, you can most likely leave it alone.

Comment: To rotate text, do I need to call the matrix by cairo_get_matrix ? or calling cairo_rotate() function would do the job ?

Comment: cairo_rotate() does the job. Internally, it uses the matrix functions, but that's nothing which you have to know to use it. cairo_rotate() should be way easier to use anyway. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Uli Schlachter : Thats all I wanted to know :)